# What METHOD do I use for a Delayed Capture process?

Tags: paypal

The documentation I see says I should be making a call and passing an ORIGID.  But, what is the METHOD?  Straight from the documentation:

> TRXTYPE=D&TENDER=C&PWD=x1y2z3&PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=.SuperMerchant
>   &USER=SuperMerchant&ORIGID=VXYZ00887892

Okay, that's awesome.  How do I actually make that call?  Am I using the wrong API's?  I have been doing a DoCapture, but this requires a three step process to get a Transaction ID, which appears to be vastly different from this ORIGID.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal has several flavors of APIs. The API string you listed is an example of the Payflow Pro API suite which is commonly used by merchants who use PayPal as a payment gateway only. It does not have a METHOD: instead TRXTYPE=D specifies that it is a delayed capture. For more info on Payflow API you should refer to https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_guide.pdf.

Comment: Gah, I was way off.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a long time.  The PayPal folks don't seem to understand .NET much. So I finally got it to work this way (.Net solution).  This solution uses an added user (test123)I created at PayPal:

```html
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myTokenRequest = "PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=kathypatrick77&USER=test123&PWD=test321&TRXTYPE=A&AMT=2.00&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=20128208de1413abc3d60c86v46yd+@dffg5";

            HttpWebRequest wrWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com");
            wrWebRequest.Method = "POST";
           
            StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(wrWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
            requestWriter.Write(myTokenRequest);
            requestWriter.Close();

            HttpWebResponse hwrWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrWebRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(wrWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

            //and read the response
            string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            TextBox1.Text = responseData.ToString();
            responseReader.Close();
        }
```